# Realm using preloaded database in android

Tags: android, database, realm

Can someone guide me how to use preloaded Realm database?

I have an external Realm Database I need to import it into my android application.

Thanks In Advance

Comment: You could take a look at our migration example https://github.com/realm/realm-java/tree/master/examples/migrationExample . It has some preloaded Realm db in `res/raw` directory. And they are copied and opened in the main activity here https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/examples/migrationExample/src/main/java/io/realm/examples/realmmigrationexample/MigrationExampleActivity.java